# Command line progress bar like node.js

Tags: language-agnostic, command-line-interface

Does anyone know how to recreate this? I guess I could look at node.js' source, but I'm too lazy.

I know how to do command line progress bars, but I'm interested in this one, since it doesn't look like ASCII characters and I don't know what produces it.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like it's still just printing characters.

Depending on the font, it might be using something specific to a PC (e.g., 176, 177, 178 in the normal text-mode characters of an average PC), or it might be using some unicode characters such as U+2591 for the lighter-colored part, and U+2593 for the darker-colored part.